# Compare ObservableCollection with Toggle Button listBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, observablecollection, togglebutton

i have listbox taht fill with list of toggle button in after run the project, if i have observablecollection and i want to compare this ObservableCollection with items in list box where if the item in ObservableCollection exist in listbox i want to make this item (toggle button) checked,

i have tryed to do that but i cant access to toggle button in code behind, becouse the list of toggle buttons show after run the project.

here's my listbox code :

```
 <ListBox x:Name="lbname" ItemsSource="{Binding source}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ToggleButton x:Name="btnitem" Content="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

and my observableCollection :

```
  IQueryable<items> query = _context.items;
  ocitems = new ObservableCollection<items>(query);
```

In short : How can i compare ObservableCollection items with listbox (Buttons) and if item exist in listbox make the Toggle button that represent the item is checked?

hope this clear.

------------------------------------------ More Detail

i have this list box that show choices for selected item, this listBox filled by ObservableCollection "ocSelectedChoice" :

[image]

```
    <ListBox x:Name="lbChoices" ItemsSource="{Binding ocSelectedChoice}" DisplayMemberPath="ChoiceName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="165" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="186" Margin="567,50,0,0" BorderBrush="#FFC1C1C1" Background="#FFE3E3E3" SelectionMode="Extended">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFc4d0df"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFC1C1C1"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0.8"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
```

when i want to change this item choices, i press the edit button,and will show me windows that has listbox filled by ObservableCollection for all available choices, see the photo, the main problem how to make 'choices 1' lock checked (green one) in choices windows:

[image]

```
    <ItemsControl x:Name="icItemGroup" ItemsSource="{Binding PagedSource, ElementName=rdpChoices}" Margin="26,79,0,0" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="506" Height="210" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
        <!-- ItemsPanelTemplate -->
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="4" HorizontalAlignment="left" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <!-- ItemTemplate -->
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ToggleButton x:Name="tbtnChoices" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="tahoma" FontSize="12" Height="45" Width="120" FontWeight="Normal" Margin="0,0,0,5" Background="#FFE8E8E8" BorderBrush="#FFC1C1C1" Foreground="#FF6A6A6A"
                              Content="{Binding ChoiceName}" TabIndex="{Binding ChoicesID}" Click="tbtnChoices_Click">
                    <ToggleButton.IsChecked>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Choices}">
                          <Binding Path="ocChoice" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </ToggleButton.IsChecked>
                </ToggleButton>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Converter :

```
    public class ChoicesConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter,
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Choice _choice = values[0] as Choice;
        ObservableCollection<Choice> ocChoices = values[1] as ObservableCollection<Choice>;
        return ocChoices.Contains(_choice);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter,
                                System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

i tried to make this, but sorry still there something unclear for me, please help to solved this issue because it's important for my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oky, i solved it, here's my code :

This is the converter :

```
    public class IsSelectedChoiceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool _check = false;
        if (value == null)
            return false;
        Item currentItem = (Item)value;
        if (currentItem.ChoicesinItem.Count == 0)
            _check = false;
        foreach (var _choicesinItem in currentItem.ChoicesinItem)
        {
            if (currentItem.CurrentChoiceId == _choicesinItem.ChoicesId)
                _check = true;
        }
        return _check;
    }
```

and xaml code :

```
                    <ToggleButton x:Name="tbtnChoices" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="tahoma" FontSize="12" Height="45" Width="120" FontWeight="Normal" Margin="0,0,0,5" Background="#FFE8E8E8" BorderBrush="#FFC1C1C1" Foreground="#FF6A6A6A"
                              IsChecked="{Binding Path=Item,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource IsSelectedChoice}}"
                              Content="{Binding Item.CurrentChoiceName}" TabIndex="{Binding Item.CurrentChoiceId}" Click="tbtnChoices_Click">
                </ToggleButton>
```

it's work now, Thanks for anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the multivalue converter to do that i.e bind ToggleButton IsChecked like below:

```
      <ListBox x:Name="lbname" ItemsSource="{Binding source}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ToggleButton x:Name="btnitem" Content="{Binding Name}">
                        <ToggleButton.IsChecked>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}">
                                <Binding />
                                <Binding Path="DataContext.ObservableCollectionToCompare" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </ToggleButton.IsChecked>
                    </ToggleButton>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Here I am assuming that the observalblecollectin to which you want to compare is a property in your view's DataContext.
MyConverter is the multivalue converter that you need to create.
And in the Convert method of your converter you can compare if the item is there in the collection and return true of false accordingly.

```
public class MyConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter,
                              System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {

            Item listItem = values[0] as Item;
            ObservableCollection<Item> collection = values[1] as ObservableCollection<Item>;

            return collection.Contains(listItem);
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter,
                                    System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please can you help me to create the converter

Comment: updated my question with more detail, please can you help to solve this issue.